# How to solve hard integral of Gaussian/ Normal distribution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

How to find $$ {\displaystyle \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} A x^2 {\rm e}^{- x^2/2 \sigma^2} d x} $$ where A is a constant given that 
$$ {\displaystyle \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} A {\rm e}^{- x^2/2 \sigma^2} d x = 1} $$

The expression inside the second integral being the Gaussian or Normal Distribution.

Please help, i know by parts works but could someone please outline some main steps and an answer please as it has me really confused

Comment: Integration by parts works.

Comment: i know it does but i cant work out how to do it, could you show me?

Comment: Before editing the question, you had said that you tried by parts. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: There are only three factors in the integrand, so a very small number of choices for $u$.  Which ones did you try already?

Comment: i keep on coming up with error functions in my answer or my answer is zero, it literally falls apart everywhere im afraid

Comment: ive tried u as the exponential and as x^2, both times im still not getting a correct answer.

Comment: that leaves...?

Comment: No, $A$ is a constant.

Comment: so it doesnt leave anything surely?

Comment: Think about that exponential.  Why doesn't $e^{-x^2}$ have an elementary antiderivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

When you integrate by parts, you must choose a factor that you can integrate, and that later leads to a simplification of the integrand. Here you can split in three ways

- $1\cdot x^2e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$,
- $x\cdot xe^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$,
- $x^2\cdot e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$.

Among these options you must investigate which factor you are able to integrate, and from this how the next integrand will evolve.

Sometimes integration requires to roll up your sleeves.

> $$\int xe^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}\cdot x\,dx=-\sigma^2e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}\cdot x+\sigma^2\int e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

We'll first prove, then use with $B:=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$, the fact that $\int_\Bbb R Ae^{-Bx^2}dx=A\sqrt{\pi}B^{-1/2}$.

**Proof** Call this integral $I$ so$$I^2=\int_{\Bbb R^2}A^2e^{-B(x^2+y^2)}dxdy.$$This is a double integral over the plane. Since $dxdy=rdrd\theta$,$$I^2=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty A^2re^{-Br^2}drd\theta=2\pi A^2[-\tfrac{1}{2B}e^{-Br^2}]_0^\infty=\frac{\pi A^2}{B}.$$Taking the square root completes the proof, as clearly $I>0$.

**Corollary** Differentiating with respect to $-B$ gives$$\int_\Bbb R Ax^2e^{-Bx^2}dx=\frac12A\sqrt{\pi}B^{-3/2}\implies\int_\Bbb R Ax^2e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}dx=A\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^3.$$The choice $A=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ verifies the famous $N(0,\,\sigma^2)$ PDF does, in fact, have variance $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is the standard normal distribution with mean $=0$ and variance $=\sigma^2$.  Therefore $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$.       The first integral $=\sigma^2$.

To integrate by parts use $u=x$ and $dv=xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$  You will have an expression $B=C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$
Work with $B^2$.  Convert to polar coordinates and you will get the final expression $B^2=\sigma^4$.

Details for use of polar coordinates:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}dxdy$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}rdrd\theta$$=2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{u}{\sigma^2}}du$$=2\pi\sigma^2$

Comment: The second integral is given. I doubt that the OP can implement the polar trick.

Comment: yeah, i have no idea how that polar magic occurs

Comment: Added to answer for use of polar